# How to run QT designer studio application in ipad

Tags: qt, qml, qmake, qt-designer

I developed a qml application using designer studio and i want to run application in iPAD.
How to run QT designer studio application in my ipad

Comment: Just follow any toturial, how to build Qt applications for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Qt Design Studio for doing your UI Design in QML and your app is written in C++, you would need to use X Code or Qt Creator in order to build your IOS app. Just bring your qml project into your c++ project, make the bindings to the backend and then build your app from there. Here is a starting point for that - doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-ios.html